# FQL: group results that have a field in common

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm developing an application based on the facebook checkins.
I'm searching a way to group the results, that I receive asking for an user's checkins, by the page_id with a single FQL query.
Generally I would try with the GROUP clause of the SQL language but i read that this clause isn't supported by FQL.

Thanks in advance,

Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no GROUP BY available, as you said, this is not possible via a single FQL query.

Your options are to either do that yourself while processing the data you received by looping over it and transfering it into the desired data structure, or *if you know what pages are involved beforehand*, by doing a multi query including one single query for every page_id.

Comment: Ok, since I don't exactly know what pages are involved I have to group the result by myself by code. I hoped there was a faster way.